# R: Remove text within (and including) parentheses in a oarticular data frame column

Tags: r, regex

I have a data frame in which one of the columns contains comma separated text strings (attached snapshot). I want to delete all the text within the parentheses (including the parentheses itself).

I have read through the regex but I an not able to get a clear idea to do so. I small hint shall help me to begin understand how regex can be used in R. Any resources one would like to point me towards for R?

[Attached snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRqGV.jpg)

Can anybody direct me towards any post that discusses it? Apparently, somebody decided to mark my questin as duplicate without telling which is the 'original' post.

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't provide a reproducible example. Maybe you can try `gsub("\\s*\\([^\\)]*\\)\\s*","",x)` where `x` is the `character` vector containing the strings you want to modify.

Comment: Hi Nicola, Basically I want a entry such as **computer(laptop, mouse), chair** to become **computer, chair** . In summary, I want the text within the parentheses to be deleted along with the parentheses itself.